# How to target multiple class outside the div

Tags: jquery

I need to target the class outside a div by clicking a header (h2). Apparently it is not working with .next() and also by .closest().

```
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="spacer m-t-40"></div>
     <h2 class="subtitle m-t-0 m-b-10">Who's Placing this ad?<h2>
   </div>
   <div class="accrodion-list container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="sm-mb">(This will not be published)</p>
        <div class="spacer m-t-45"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="spacer m-t-40"></div>
     <h2 class="subtitle m-t-0 m-b-10">Who is this ad for?<h2>
   </div>
   <div class="accrodion-list container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="sm-mb">(This will not be published)</p>
        <div class="spacer m-t-45"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>  


$('.subtitle').each(function(){
        $(this).click( function() {
            var close = $(this).next('.accrodion-list');
                console.log($(close));
        })
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean by target the class outside a div by clicking the a header ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do something akin to:  `$("h2").on("click", function(){ $(this).next().slideToggle(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it now. Since it has separate parent div I need to target it first before doing next()

```
$('.subtitle').each(function(){
    $(this).click( function() {
        var close = $(this).parents('div').next('.accrodion-list');
            console.log($(close));
            $(close).slideToggle();
    })
})
```